# How to make the 3d manipulator act parallel to a plane

Tags: mesh

How would i be able to set my 3d manipulator so that one of the axis is parallel to the face of what im moving, i want to move it parallel to the face of the plane.

Answer (score 4):

1. Select (a face in) the plane
2. Create a Custom Orientation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>)
3. (Check 'Use after creation' and possibly 'Overwrite previous' in the tool region,if you don't want to bother to name the orientation, and/or don't need it later)
4. Any translation you now make with <kbd>G</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will be parallel to the plane you selected.

Comment: That should so much be in the menu or as an option in the Transform Orientation tool instead of being hidden away on a hotkey.

Comment: I guess the difficulty in simply including custom orientations in the dropdown is the desire to stash them for future use. But nearly all of mine are 'disposable', so yes, a 'From Selection' option in the orientation dropdown would be very handy.

Answer (score 2):

Change the Transform Orientation at the bottom of the 3D Editor window from the default of 'Global' to 'Local'. This will use the object's local axis for manipulation.

Comment: You may need to temporarily join your objects to use this method, but it should work.

Comment: Yes - this only works to manipulate an object to its *own* local orientation.

Comment: I like this approach, because then you could duplicate your reference object, and parent your target object to that. Translate the duplicated parent, clear the parent, then delete the duplicate reference object (or keep it parented on a separate later, and/or disable it from rendering). This could be useful if you ever wanted to use snapping to get it back into its original starting position (eg. Snap Duplicate Parent Reference Origin to a 3D Cursor position set to the Origin of the Original Reference).